# Keras image classification network always predicting one class, and stays at 50% accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I've been working on a Keras network to classify images as to whether they contain traffic lights or not, but so far I've had 0 success. I have a dataset of 11000+ images, and for my first test I used 240 images (or rather, text files for each image with the grayscale pixel values). There is only one output - a 0 or 1 saying whether the image contains traffic lights.

However, when I ran the test, it only predicted one class. Given that 53/240 images had traffic lights, it was achieving about a 79% accuracy rate because it was just predicting 0 all the time. I read that this might be down to inbalanced data, so I downscaled to just 4 images - 2 with traffic lights, 2 without.

Even with this test, it still stuck at 50% accuracy after 5 epochs; it's just predicting one class! Similar questions have been answered but I haven't found anything that is working for me :(

Here is the code I am using:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import os

train_images = []
train_labels = []

#The following is just admin tasks - extracting the grayscale pixel values
#from the text files, adding them to the input array. Same with the labels, which
#are extracted from text files and added to output array. Not important to performance. 

for fileName in os.listdir('pixels1/'):
    newRead = open(os.path.join('pixels1/', fileName))

    currentList = []
    for pixel in newRead:
        rePixel = int(pixel.replace('\n', ''))/255
        currentList.append(rePixel)
    train_images.append(currentList)

        
for fileName in os.listdir('labels1/'):
    newRead = open(os.path.join('labels1/', fileName))
    line = newRead.readline()
    train_labels.append(int(line))

train_images = np.array(train_images)
train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

train_images = train_images.reshape((4,13689))

#model

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(13689, input_dim=13689, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(13689, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=1)
```

I was hoping at the very least it would be able to recognise the images at the end. I really want to move onto running a training session on my full 11,000 examples, but at this point I can't get it to work with 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rough points:

1. You seem to believe that the number of units in your dense layers should be equal to your data dimension (13869); this is **not** the case. Change both of them to something smaller (in the range of 100-200) - they do not even have to be equal. A model that big is not recommended with your relatively small number of data samples (images).
2. Since you are in a binary classification setting with a single node in your last layer, you should use `activation=sigmoid` for this (last) layer, and compile your model with `loss='binary_crossentropy'`.
3. In imaging applications, normally the first couple of layers are convolutional ones.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for your answer. I made changes 1 & 2 to my model with no success. However, when I run it for 20+ epochs, it eventually gets to 1. I thought this was a win and scaled it up to 240 images again, but with that it does the same thing - stays firm a 79%. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoshuaPotts well, a 79% accuracy compared to the 50% you reported initially (i.e. random guessing) sounds like a big progress - so it's *not* the same thing. I'm not sure what you mean you "scaled up" your model, but in any case 240 images does not sound like a lot. Next step is to try to incorporate convolutional layers; but the idea here was not to give a complete tutorial (which is out of scope for SO), only to pinpoint some classic mistakes in your approach.

Comment: Okay, got it. Actually it is stuck at 79% which is what it would get it if just guessed (137 out of 240 images do not have traffic lights). However, when I upped the epochs to 400 and changed the batch size, it eventually reaches 1, so I think I've succeeded. Thanks for your help!